# C++ print a reverse heart shape

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vowm1.png)

Hello everyone, I am trying to print a reverse heart shape in c++. While user will input a integer, and the program will display the reverse heart according to the value.
in the photo, the input value are 1,3,4

Now my code can only show the triangle but still missing the two small triangle, so hoping can get some guide here.

```
int size,space;
cout << "Input size: ";
cin >> size;
int rows = (size * 2)+1;
for (int i = 1, k = 0; i <= rows; ++i, k = 0)
{
    for (space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space)
    {
        cout << "  ";
    }

    while (k != 2 * i - 1)
    {
        cout << "* ";
        ++k;
    }
    cout << endl;


}
```

{

```
    for (int i = size; i >= 1; --i)
    {
        for (int space = 0; space < size - i; ++space)
            cout << "  ";

        for (int j = i; j <= 2 * i - 1; ++j)
            cout << "* ";

        for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j)
            cout << "* ";

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I try to print a Inverted first, but I fail to print two at the same time.

Comment: Look at your example data. For each line after the big triangle, write down the number of spaces, then asterisks, spaces, then asterisks.  Is there a pattern?  How does this pattern relate the the input number?

Comment: hi, thank you for your help, this is my first time to try c++. I found that the row of the triangle is depend on the input and the space there actually is another triangle. But I am still not available to solve it, would you mind to show some step or code as sample to try?